# What is the best way to support multiple languages in a JS web app?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, translation

I am currently working to implement multiple language support in a web app. Large parts of the website exist inside a canvas element, this means that auto-translate from browsers cannot translate it.

Currently I am working on a system where language variations are stored in an object like this:

```
export const TextContent = {
    en: ['Hello', 'Goodbye'],
    de: ['Hallo', 'Auf Wiedersehen'],
    fr: ['Bonjour', 'Au revoir'],
}
```

The content for the website is then generated with code like this:
`createElement('div', TextContent['en'][0])` or `canvas.drawText(..., TextConent['en'][0])`

However I don't think this is the best way to do it.
I have read other posts online were people recommend storing all of the text in JSON files like this:

```
content.en.json
{
    "hello": "hello"
}

content.fr.json
{
    "hello": "Bonjour"
}
```

This seems a bit cumbersome to me. I have also seen examples of people storing languages in key-value pair files. Such as

```
content.en.txt
hello=Hello
goodbye=Goodbye

content.fr.txt
hello=Bonjour
goodbye=Au revoir
```

Neither of those methods, or my own one, seem particularly good.

I am not using any framework like React or Vue.

What is the industry standard for this? Are there any good NPM packages for implementing this. I would really appreciate some advice. Thank you.

Comment: your approach is fine, the only thing, you might be better off working with keys rather than numeric indexes, e.g. `TextContent['en'].helloMsg`

Comment: Yes I think that would be a good addition. Only issue with that is there is then a lot of extra bloat as each language needs to define `helloMsg: 'hello'` rather than just `'hello'`. This will definitely add up in the long run as ~1000 phrases need to be added. However I suppose there isn't any way around that. Thank you for the suggestion.